# Problem with using regex_match in Redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I am using following code for regular expression matching but getting this error:

Error:

> Invalid operation: function regexp_matches(character varying, character varying) does not exist;

Code:

```
WHEN REGEXP_MATCHes (tdahw.referrer, 'www.*/'::text) IS NOT NULL AND     REGEXP_MATCHes(tdahw.event_value, 'www.*/'::text) = REGEXP_MATCHes(tdahw.referrer, 'www.*/'::text) AND tdahw.rolling_count = 1 THEN 'Direct'::text
WHEN REGEXP_MATCHes(tdahw.referrer, 'www.*/'::text) IS NOT NULL AND REGEXP_MATCHes(tdahw.event_value, 'www.*/'::text) <> REGEXP_MATCHes(tdahw.referrer, 'www.*/'::text) AND tdahw.rolling_count = 1 THEN 'Referrer'::text
WHEN REGEXP_MATCHes(tdahw.referrer, 'www.*/'::text) IS NULL THEN 'Referrer'::text
```

How can it be rectified?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Sample data and expected result:
    www.abcd.com/xyz and https://www.abcd.com/def should be treated as equal
    www.abcd.com and https://www.abcd.com/xyz should be treated as equal.
    www.abcd.com/xyz and www.abcdef.com/xyz should be treated as not equal.
    www.abcd.com/xyz and www.xyz.com/pqr should be treated as not equal

Answer (score 0):

Use `~`:

```
WHEN tdahw.referrer ~ 'www.*/'::text AND 
     tdahw.event_value ~ 'www.*/'::text AND
     tdahw.referrer ~ 'www.*/'::text AND
     tdahw.rolling_count = 1
```

Comment: Are these cases handled in above approach? 
1)REGEXP_MATCHes(tdahw.event_value, 'www.*/'::text) = REGEXP_MATCHes(tdahw.referrer, 'www.*/'::text)
2) REGEXP_MATCHes (tdahw.referrer, 'www.*/'::text) IS NOT NULL

Comment: @slayer1996 . . . `~` returns a boolean.  You are trying to compare the results from two matches?

Comment: Yes. The part after AND in the first line of the query is a comparison